# Como enviar erros e exceções à saída principal?

Tags: ruby, apache

Estou usando o Ruby 2.1 32 bits.
Interpretando scripts como CGI pelo do Apache 2. Através do IP Local.

Estou em um processo de migração de vários script em PHP para Ruby.

Durante o processo de escrita de código, várias vezes erro tanto em digitação como em alguns conceitos novos sobre a linguagem e suas diversas bibliotecas. O problema é que toda vez que acontece um erro ou exceção, o Apache apenas retorna o Erro 500. E por seguinte, tenho que abrir os logs de erro do Apache checar as mensagens meio confusas, o que me toma tempo útil de codificação.

Minha questão, há alguma maneira de enviar os error e exceções para a saída padrão para que eles sejam mostrados no Browser e não apenas sejam reconhecidos pelo servidor?

Comment: Não sei exatamente como está organizado seu código, nem tenho experiência com CGI, mas não seria mais fácil simplesmente rodar seus scripts manualmente pela linha de comando e checar os resultados?

Comment: Seria um despejo de tempo parecido com o atual. Visto que teria que alternar bastante entre o browser e o terminal. Mas valeu a opção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução mais simples é definir a saída de erros global como a saída padrão no início do seu script:

```
$stderr = STDOUT
```

`STDOUT` é o objeto de `IO` que representa a saída padrão.

Comment: A linha acima não funcionou. Na verdade gerou algum erro sinistro que eu tive que olhar no log do Apache (500) e não apareceu qualquer mensagem vinda do Ruby.

Comment: Hmm, poderia mostrar o erro? Tentei rodar um script com essa definição no topo do arquivo e os erros acabam sendo reportados na saída padrão.

Comment: `[Mon Apr 27 17:20:46.925038 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 5188:tid 952] [client ::1:65332] Premature end of script headers: index.rb`

Comment: Poderia postar um exemplo de script seu? Parece que o redirecionamento tem que ocorrer depois do setup do CGI, de acordo cob esta página http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=262011 Não entendo muito do workflow do CGI, então estou chutando algumas coisas no escuro; se conseguir ver o código talvez fique mais fácil.

Comment: O "setup" do CGI está no `initialize` de uma classe quase ao final do arquivo. O código a ser _debugado_ vai provavelmente estar sempre acima do código do setup.

Comment: Essa linha tem que ficar depois do setup, idealmente logo antes do seu código que gera erros ser executado, de modo a não interferir com a execução do setup.

Comment: Tive problemas com meu servidor. Assim que puder testar novamente volto aqui. Agradeço a disposição.